# Add fonts in React-Native ios and lose it after restart + Apple match-0 linter

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have install Lato font on my react-native app. All was working perfectly but after take a break and restart the project. I got a red screen who say `unrecognized font-family lato-regular`

And now when I try to build in Xcode I got `Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group` `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I try to find a way to remove it but everything I found on the web didn't work.

But like I say before I close Xcode and come back to my code everything was fine.

## Versions

- React-Native 0.34
- Xcode 8
- Ios 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I got the same file two times. So I just remove it and clean + build.

I got two an other error but that was cause I didn't follow the installation of facebookSDK.

This is what I've miss to add to AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  #if DEBUG
   jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
  #else
   // For production load from pre-bundled file on disk. To re-generate the static bundle, run
   //
   // $ curl http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle -o main.jsbundle
   jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
  #endif
  NSDictionary *props = @{@"user" : @"null"};
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                        moduleName:@"nameofmyapp"
                                                 initialProperties:nil
                                                     launchOptions:launchOptions];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  // return YES;
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

// Facebook SDK
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error occurs because files have not been correctly linked in your project.

[This article](https://medium.com/@dabit3/adding-custom-fonts-to-react-native-b266b41bff7f#.8c9sv9ri3) provides a good guide to adding custom fonts. Make sure that you follow steps #3 and #4, especially.

> **Step 3: Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle**
>
> Click on your Xcode project file in the left hand column, then select “Build Phases”. Make sure that your font has been added under “Copy Bundle Resources” (this should have been done automatically).
>
> **Step 4: Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist**
>
> In your main app folder in your Xcode project, select info.plist. After this is selected, click on “Information Property List”, and then click the plus sign. In the dropdown, choose “Fonts provided by application”. Copy and paste the exact name of the file under “Value” on the right hand column of this row.

Then clean (Command-Option-Shift-K), and rebuild your project to see if it clears the error.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did all you say and that was the third time I check and still got error. The build failed and this is not caused of the fonts so I think because of the fail I don't get it.

Comment: `Showing Recent Issues
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`